# why pytest testcase with @pytest.mark.asyncio still run in sync mode but not async mode?

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio

I have testcase with pytest like below:

**test_tmp.py**

```py
import logging
import pytest
import asyncio
import time


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async_01():
    logging.info(f"time => {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async_02():
    logging.info(f"time => {time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

When I try to run this test module with command **pytest test_tmp.py**, what I expect is these two cases run almost at the same time as its **@pytest.mark.asyncio** marked, should run with **async** mode, but in fact, it looks run one by one with **sync** mode, is there something wrong with my code? or how to do to make it works as expect?

**NOTE: I didn't override event_loop fixture, it should used the default one.**

**The related screenshot like below:**
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAQxC.png

Comment: pytest executes one test at a time, it has nothing to do with sync/async

Comment: Oh, maybe I have misunderstand what pytest-asyncio used for... As testcase groups very fast, if pytest only support run cases one by one, it will take a very long time to finished all of them, so I really want to run cases with async mode, I also tried pytest-xdist, but it needs a better machine hardware support, do you have any good idea for this?